# Select all user who isn't in a team

Tags: php, sql

My database looks something like this, in order of user, userteam (connection table) and team:

```
    Usertable              UserTeam              Teamtable
+--------+------+    +--------+--------+    +--------+-------+
| userid | name |    | userid | teamid |    | teamid | name  |
+--------+------+    +--------+--------+    +--------+-------+
| 1      | eric |    | 1      |      1 |    |      1 | awsm  |
| 2      | john |    | 1      |      2 |    |      2 | doe   |   
| 3      | carl |    | 2      |      1 |    |      3 | empty |
+--------+------+    | 3      |      1 |    +--------+-------+
                     +--------+--------+
```

How do I select all users that IS NOT in a team, and echo them out only once? I've tried doing it with the usertable, but then it will echo for instance, if I try and select all members not in team 3:

```
SELECT userid FROM userteam WHERE teamid!=3;
SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid='$previousSql';

1 eric
1 eric
2 john
3 carl
```

What I'd like instead is:

```
1 eric
2 john
3 carl
```

I'm making an add members function, and I'd very much not like everyone to show up more than once.. Any directions, help or guiding would be much appreciated.

Comment: please add group by in query e.g. SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid='$previousSql' group by name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT u.userid, u.name FROM Usertable u
INNER JOIN UserTeam ut ON ut.userid = u.userid
INNER JOIN Teamtable tt ON tt.teamid = ut.teamid
WHERE tt.teamid != 3
GROUP BY u.userid, u.name;
```

Comment: What's that single 'u' doing?

Comment: The u is an alias for Usertable

Comment: Oh right, okay. I'm a little confused, but I'll try and read up on it. Is it necessary?

Comment: Also, is it not a problem that you `SELECT u.userid, u.name` before adding the alias?

Comment: Well the alias isn't necessary you can instead use `Usertable.userid`, but I would definitely read up on `JOINS`

Comment: No that isn't a problem because the order of operation in sql is: FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
ORDER BY clause

Comment: Alright, cool. I still seem to be getting people that is already in the team though..

Comment: I get 5 members from the team (which I don't wanna see), + 2 members not in the team with the !=3 WHERE clause, and with =3 WHERE clause I get the 5 members in the team.. Problem's definitely on my part, not exactly sure why though..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99944/discussion-between-john-smith-and-daan).

Answer (score 1):

add

```
GROUP BY name
```

to the query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userid, name FROM usertable 
JOIN userteam ON userteam.userid = usertable.userid 
JOIN teamtable on teamtable.teamid = userteam.teamid
WHERE teamtable.teamid = 3;
```

The SQL above should do the proper joins between all the tables and then will only list the userid/names of people who have a teamid of 3 in the teamtable

EDIT* Removed ! from WHERE clause.